# Thin server used more memory on only single request in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, memory, out-of-memory, thin

I am using thin web server and only one Rails application running on server. When I execute application so it's used around 80% memory of the server only for one request.

Currently only 4 lines HTML code on application landing page so not understood why consume so much memory for only 1 request.

I tried but not understood that it's a problem of Thin web server or Rails application?

I am using

```
===================
Hosting: Digital Ocean
RAM: 2 GB
===================
```

**# Config/staging.thin.yml**

```
user: xxx
group: xxx
pid: tmp/pids/thin.pid
timeout: 30
wait: 30
log: log/thin.log
max_conns: 512
require: []
environment: staging
max_persistent_conns: 512
servers: 1
threaded: true
no-epoll: true
daemonize: true
socket: tmp/sockets/thin.sock
chdir: /home/xxx/current
tag: staging-thin
```

Any one friend have idea or experience of this issue.

Comment: Dont use Rails for just landing page. It's like to fire a cannon at sparrows. Use sinatra, cuba or a plain html.

Comment: I am running a web application but just for checking memory leaking convert into 4 line HTML.

Comment: Is this question about the memory leaking or the memory usage?

Comment: Regarding more memory used on single request. More request then site down.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your efforts.

I found some issues regarding queries which execute in background.

Thanks for your support.